# Compiling Dust templates from Different Sources

Tags: express, dust.js

I am trying to compile and render a Dust template in Express using content from two different sources:

1. Dust files located under the /views directory
2. A response as a string from an external CDN

My goal is to receive a string response from the CDN, which will have content referencing the Dust files stored locally in /views. It will look something like this:

```
"{>layout/}
 {<content}
 <h1>Here is the dynamic content that will change based on the CDN request</h1>
 {<content}"
```

The layout.dust file is stored locally under /views, which is referenced from the CDN's string response.

I am trying to compile the string response in my route by doing:

```
var compiled = dust.compile(templateStr, 'catalog_template');
dust.loadSource(compiled);

dust.render('catalog_template', dustParams, function(err, out) {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   }

   console.log(out);
   res.render(out);
});
```

But rendering the file causes an error:

```
[Error: Template Not Found: layout]
```

So somehow I need to compile the CDN's string with layout.dust (which is located in my /views directory). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to compile layout.dust by itself and when you render the CDN template, dust will pull in the layout partial. You can have dust dynamically compile templates from your filesystem like so:

```
dust.onLoad = function (name, callback) {
    // Get src from filesystem
    fs.readFile('path to template', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(err, data.toString());
    });
}
```

Make sure you require the node fs module in your code.

Comment: I thought you compiled dust templates using the dust.compile(src, name) function shown in this [documentation](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#compiling-a-dust-template). I will look into your method above. Thanks!

Comment: It does the compilation under the hood. This method means you don't manually compile the templates. You simply reference them and if they're not in the Dust cache, Dust will fetch the template using `onLoad` and then compile it. The next time you want to use it, it will be in the cache so Dust won't need to load and compile it again. If you prefer, you can load all template's in from the file system at app start and compile them using `dust.compile`. The result will end up being the same.

Comment: Further to this, if you want to see how this works, check out the `dust.load` function in the source. It should all be pretty self explanatory.